# How much food is needed for three months of food when rowing across an ocean?

Tags: food, sea

Related to this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/how-much-can-kayaking-across-the-atlantic-cost), if one were to go on a three-month rowing trip across an ocean, is there an estimate of how much the food would be needed?

It's certainly possible to give an estimate when backpacking, but rowing would be different and while I am sure that it would depend on the person, it should still be possible to get an idea.

What is an estimate of how much three months of food for a single person rowing across an ocean would be needed?

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15400/do-raw-eggs-need-to-be-rotated-for-freshness-on-a-long-voyage

Comment: Honestly, if one wanted to do they should probably start by estimating the amount of food for a one week or so testrun. We could throw ballpark estimates at this like 5000-6000kcal per day for strenuous exercise under risk of hypothermia, but there are going to be large differences based on things like the individual and the weather conditions.

Comment: I think the answer to this question exists in history, but my initial searches have not found it. This related article makes for interesting reading  [Rowing to Death](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102000924)